# Python - If Statement with two-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to generate a Sudoku. I thought about using an array for this. THis is how I create the array (ignore the fact that these are not correct Sudoku numbers):

```
row_array = [[1, 99],[2],[3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

It does work fine. The problem is with an `if` statement. If I do:

```
print(row_array[0][1])
```

or:

```
r = 1
print(row_array[0][r])
```

to get the "99" it does work fine! But if I use this variable method in an if statement like this:

```
if y not in row_array[1] and y not in row_array[0][r]:
    row_array[1].append(y)
```

I get the following **ERROR**:

> TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

I had the Sudoku working, but it took to much code, so I want to set up a counter to replace the rows and columns with an it. I'm aware of you guys probably already having a much better code for a sudoku, but I want to teach myself, and make the code better and shorter over time. I don't learn to code real good, by just copy someone else's idea or way to code.

Comment: Hello! Can you elaborate on how you expect the `row_array` to look if the `append` call succeeds?

Comment: by `y not in row_array[0][r]` you mean between 1 and 99 ?

Comment: That is because `row_array[0][r]` is no more a sublist but a scalar

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if y not in row_array[0][r]
```

The `in` operator checks if the left-hand side is in the sequence or iterable on the right hand side. But `type(row_array[0][r])` will return `int`, which is not an iterable.

Comment: Typo: `if y not int` -> `if y not in`

Comment: Thank you. But how do i fix this? I have no clue how to check otherwise then that.

Comment: Use `if y == row_array[0][r]`.